# How do I hide the list row separator of a SwiftUI List view for only the first and last items?

Tags: ios, swiftui

It is possible to write multiple in-line ternary statements, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Yes but SwiftUI has terrible performance with ternary, switch is the most efficient

Answer (score 0):

With the following function:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    fileprivate func hideListRowSeparatorIfFirstOrLastItem<Data: RandomAccessCollection<ID>, ID: Identifiable>(data: Data, item: ID) -> some View {
        if data.first?.id == item.id {
            listRowSeparator(.hidden, edges: .top)
        } else if data.last?.id == item.id {
            listRowSeparator(.hidden, edges: .bottom)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

You can neatly add this attribute in-line:

```
struct MyView: View {
    let model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Section") {
                ForEach(model.items) { item in
                    Text("Hello \(item.value)")
                        .hideListRowSeparatorIfFirstOrLastItem(data: model.items, item: item)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```